# Difficulty Storing Consensus-Derived Value in Storage: Observing Value in Pallet Log but Not in Storage

Tags: pallet, storage, consensus, babe, aura

I'm trying to store a value obtained from the consensus, specifically `sc_consensus_babe::fn import_block`. While I can observe the value in the pallet through the log, it doesn't seem to be stored in the storage.

What could be the issue, or is it not possible to store this value?

Related code:

```rust
    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn tmp)]
    pub type Temp<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, u32, ValueQuery>;

impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
 pub fn store_value(new_value: u32) -> () {
            Temp::<T>::put(10);

            // log::info!("new value in the pallet is {:?}!!!!!!", new_value);
        }
}
```